# Using Pinia with Vue.js Web components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, store, web-component, pinia

**Question has been updated**

I'm trying to use a *Pinia*'s store with web components created with *Vue.js* but I have this error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: injection "Symbol(pinia)" not found at <HelloWorld.ce msg="message" >

I have a dead simple exemple.

1. main.ts

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.ce.vue'

const ExampleElement = defineCustomElement(HelloWorld)
customElements.define('hello-world', ExampleElement)
```

2. store.ts

```
import { defineStore, createPinia, setActivePinia } from "pinia";

setActivePinia(createPinia());

export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: () => ({
    counter: 0,
  }),

  actions: {
    increment() {
      this.counter++;
    },
  },
});
```

3. HelloWorld.ce.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useCounterStore } from '../store.ts'

defineProps<{ msg: string }>()

const store = useCounterStore()
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <div class="card">
    <button type="button" @click="store.increment()">count is {{ store.counter }}</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: A very specific question; and (probably) not Web Component related. Contact Pinia on their Github site: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues

Comment: Hello @Danny'365CSI'Engelman. Thanks to your advice, I was able to find [this discussion on Github](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1085) that helped me. Now I'm having a different issue, I'll update my question but I do think that it might be useful for more people, so I'll keep the question alive.

Answer (score 1):

You're recreating pinia in the store after already creating it in main.js. Remove these lines from your store:

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
const pinia = createPinia()
```

Comment: Hello, I don't create the store twice. The first block of code was straight from the doc to explain how to init pinia. It's not part of my code. I was able to get the store working but now I run into a different issue. I'll update my question.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime @AmauryHanser?

Comment: @ShadowGames well, except for the warning it was working. In the meatime, we have decided to move away from web components because we had to many issues regarding styling slots.